# How can I display information with foreign key in repeater?

Tags: c#, foreach, foreign-keys, repeater

I have the class `Rating`, this is the constructive action:

```
public Rating(int ratingId, int userId, int theRating, string feedback)
{
    this.ratingId++;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.theRating = theRating;
    this.feedback = feedback;
}
```

I also have the class `MyUser`:

```
public MyUser(string userName, string password, string email)
{
    this.userId++;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}
```

I have a repeater that shows the list of reviews.

My question is: Can I show the userName instead of userId in the repeater, since it is connected?

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
<asp:Label class="author" ID="useridtoname" runat="server" Text=<%#Eval("userId")%>></asp:Label>
```

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterC.Items)
{
    var lableidton = (Label)item.FindControl("useridtoname");
    var theid = Convert.ToInt32(lableidton.Text);
    MyUser nu = w.SelectUserByUserID(theid);
    lableidton.Text = nu.UserName;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the text of `useridtoname` in both the tag and the repeater loop? Have you tried only setting it in the loop?